# Search special characters in Kibana search bar

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have ELK 5.2.1 for log analysis. Now I need to search some strings via the Kibana search bar. For example, I need to find the logs include "usage:527". I understand the syntax should follow https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html. But it doesn't work for me.
I tried:

```
"usage\:527"
"usage:527"
"usage?527"
message:/usage\:527/
message:/.*usage:527.*/
```

But nothing worked. Can anyone have experience help me with it? Thanks!

I understand the use dev tool to query is alternative way but some of my ELK users don't have those kind of capability.

Here is the index detail:

```
    curl  -XGET -u elastic localhost:9200/app_web_log-20170410
Enter host password for user 'elastic':
{"app_web_log-20170410":{"aliases":{},"mappings":{"log":{"properties":{"@timestamp":{"type":"date"},"@version":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"beat":{"properties":{"hostname":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"name":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"version":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}}}},"deployment":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"input_type":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"message":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"module":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"offset":{"type":"long"},"source":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}}}}},"settings":{"index":{"creation_date":"1491782403146","number_of_shards":"5","number_of_replicas":"1","uuid":"73cWj5AHTmeFdXnJk4xCjQ","version":{"created":"5020199"},"provided_name":"app_web_log-20170410"}}}}
```

Comment: tried `{"match":{"message":"usage?275"}}` too. But still not working.

Comment: What's the mapping of your `message` field?

Comment: Message field is from logstash. It is log entry

Comment: What do you get when running `curl -XGET localhost:9200/logstash-*` ?

Comment: I got only **{}**. Actually I don't have indices start with logstahs*. I already changed to my names. But using that command also got a **{}**

Comment: What's the name of your index then?

Comment: It is app_log-*.

Comment: Then what do you get when running `curl -XGET localhost:9200/app_log-*` ?

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I got only {}. `curl  -XGET -u elastic localhost:9200/app_log-*
Enter host password for user 'elastic':
{}`

Comment: Do you really have data in your index? What about `curl -XGET -u elastic localhost:9200/*` ?

Answer (score -2):

According to your mapping, you can try the following query in Kibana if the message field contains the exact value `usage:527`:

```
message.keyword:"usage:527"
```

If `usage:527` is a substring of your message field, then you can try with a [regular expression](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_regular_expressions), like this

```
message.keyword:/usage:527/
```

Comment: Thank you. But this doesn't work too. I tried '527' and 'usage', both work. But 'usage:527' works.

Comment: Can you show the full value of the message field that contains `usage:527`?

Comment: 2017-05-28 05:26:58,024 [http-bio-8099-exec-23113] INFO  [ServiceUsageController:usage:527] 123456789012345 - 76eb59576928e53067cff5eb17c9279e token XXX-abbfd74e529c4bb665a4c696f471c221, response data :{"code":"0","token":"XXX-abbfd74e529c4bb665a4c696f471c221","properties":{"allowAppReport":0,"initPageType":2,"showPackageIcon":0,"timeZone":"GMT-03:00"},"tid":"76eb59576928e53067cff5eb17c9279e"}

Comment: I don't see `usage:527` in there. Can you check my updated answer?

Comment: thanks for asking. no luck at all. it is still the same. very curious why.

Comment: Can you update your question with a sample document you'd like to match?

Comment: Quick note to those who're downvoting: this was a post from 2017 which was never finished because the OP didn't follow up. 5 years later Kibana supports two query language (Lucene + KQL), things have changed, so just create a new thread with your issue, this one is probably not your issue anymore